# GitHub - Merging Previous Checkins

Tags: git, github, merge, squash

I have a private github repository that needs some work done.  When I first started the repository, I was new to git and I was checking in BLOBs and files containing potentially sensitive information.  Things have been corrected going forward, but the repository is giant because of the old BLOBs that used to be stored in it, plus, I'm pretty sure that the potentially sensitive information is still in the history.

Let's say my commit history looks like this:

`A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H -> I -> J -> K`

Is there a way for me to tell GitHub to merge everything between two points into one "checkin"?  For example, I'd like my repo to look like this:

`A -> [MERGE1] -> E -> F > [MERGE2] -> K`

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is probably possible using squashing or rebasing, but the repo will likely not get smaller. The old commits including the sensitive information will still be in the repository (physically in the _.git/objects_ directory), just not referenced from other commits / a branch any longer. Using command line Git there is [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to clean up such things, but as GitHub offers things like "Restore branch" I doubt they do that on their repos.

Comment: When talking about git may you use git terminology? E.g. commit instead of checkin.